# Linear Transformatonf and Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

- Let {$e_1,e_2$} be a standard basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Suppose $L:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2}$ be a linear transformation such that $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Find the matrix representation of $L$ with respect to the standard basis.

**I couldn't anything. Can you help, can you give a hint?**

Comment: Represent the standard basis vectors as linear combinations of $(1,1)$ and $(1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach. Let $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ be the matrix of $L$ with respect to the standard basis. Then $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ give the equations 
$$a+b=3, \quad  c+d=3, \quad  a-b=-1, \quad  c-d=1\,.$$ 
Solve for $a,b,c,d$.

Comment: Why $a-b=-1$ and $c-d=1$?

Comment: And How can I use $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c&d \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ becomes $\begin{pmatrix} a - b \\ c - d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Replace $L$ with the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ in $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and $L\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and do the matrix multiplication on the left hand side

Comment: $a=1$, $b=2$, $c=2$, $d=1$. Are these solution for the question?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: I didn't understand that if $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$, $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and solve for $a,b,c,d$ then why these $a,b,c,d$ is solution for the question?

Comment: That is, I didn't understand this methotd for your solution

Comment: The matrix $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ is the matrix of $L$ with respect to the standard basis

Comment: How do you know that? Tell me more please. Solution is not clear for me.

Comment: Probably, I don't know a rule of matrix rep. of linear trans (as the question and the answer)

Comment: The matrix of a linear transformation $L:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix $M$, such that $M\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y\end{pmatrix}=L(x,y)$ for every $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. We know $L(x,y)$ for some specific points $(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. These enable us to determine the matrix.

Comment: Thanks, for comments.